# Converting a single element of a nested list from factors to characters

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have created a nested list called 'mydata' from reading in all csv files from a directory:

```r
> temp <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
> ls <- lapply(temp, read.csv)
> str(mydata)
List of 4
 $ :'data.frame':   51 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ Primary.ID : Factor w/ 862 levels "X102.034169503712_9.041775",..: 564 621 527 260 566 590 625 68 699 95 ...
  ..$ PosORNeg   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Neg","Pos": 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 ...
  ..$ p.1.P      : num [1:51] -0.435 -0.278 -0.285 0.31 -0.233 ...
  ..$ p.corr..1.P: num [1:51] -0.845 -0.704 -0.598 0.644 -0.818 ...
  ..$ VIP.2.     : num [1:51] 13.17 8.24 7.76 7.69 6.84 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   32 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ Primary.ID : Factor w/ 862 levels "X102.034169503712_9.041775",..: 564 621 527 590 566 358 563 571 625 12 ...
  ..$ PosORNeg   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Neg","Pos": 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...
  ..$ p.1.P      : num [1:32] -0.468 -0.301 -0.233 -0.183 -0.142 ...
  ..$ p.corr..1.P: num [1:32] -0.916 -0.813 -0.461 -0.502 -0.705 ...
  ..$ VIP.4.     : num [1:32] 13.56 8.58 7.02 5.65 4.03 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   44 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ Primary.ID : Factor w/ 862 levels "X102.034169503712_9.041775",..: 564 527 232 381 621 590 566 54 625 40 ...
  ..$ PosORNeg   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Neg","Pos": 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 ...
  ..$ p.1.P      : num [1:44] -0.415 -0.323 0.291 -0.263 -0.279 ...
  ..$ p.corr..1.P: num [1:44] -0.919 -0.701 0.681 -0.518 -0.851 ...
  ..$ VIP.2.     : num [1:44] 11.29 8.7 8.6 7.61 7.33 ...
 $ :'data.frame':   43 obs. of  5 variables:
  ..$ Primary.ID : Factor w/ 862 levels "X102.034169503712_9.041775",..: 564 621 232 92 210 114 473 563 252 95 ...
  ..$ PosORNeg   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Neg","Pos": 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 ...
  ..$ p.1.P      : num [1:43] -0.416 -0.333 -0.251 0.189 0.168 ...
  ..$ p.corr..1.P: num [1:43] -0.73 -0.753 -0.563 0.783 0.729 ...
  ..$ VIP.2.     : num [1:43] 11.05 8.76 8.05 5.3 5.11 ...
```

I want to write code for converting each of the 'Primary.ID' columns in each of the nested lists from factors to characters, but wasn't able to figure out how to do so. Also, there were 4 csv files in the directory that I read them in from, but I'd also like the code to accommodate for a dynamic number of csv files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a tweak to your base code should solve your problem:

```
temp <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
ls <- lapply(files, function(x) read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

Similarly, a `tidyverse` solution could be:

```
library(tidyverse)

temp <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
ls <- lapply(files, read_csv)
```

Answer (score 1):

I like tomasu's answer better than mine. Nevertheless here is a way you can transform `factor` into character after reading the data.

First I create some toydata:

```
mydata <- list(data.frame(col_fac = letters[1:3], y = 3:5), 
               data.frame(col_fac = letters[4:6], z = 101:103))
str(mydata)
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ col_fac: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
  ..$ y      : int [1:3] 3 4 5
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ col_fac: Factor w/ 3 levels "d","e","f": 1 2 3
  ..$ z      : int [1:3] 101 102 103
```

Then using the `tidyverse` package:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata2 <- map(mydata, ~mutate(.x, col_fac = as.character(col_fac)))
str(mydata2)
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ col_fac: chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
  ..$ y      : int [1:3] 3 4 5
 $ :'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ col_fac: chr [1:3] "d" "e" "f"
  ..$ z      : int [1:3] 101 102 103
```